# Prove the support of a module is Noetherian

Tags: commutative-algebra

Prove that if $M$ is a Noetherian module (over an arbitrary ring $R$), then $\operatorname{Supp}M$ is a closed Noetherian subspace of $\operatorname{Spec}R$.

This is the exercise 10 of chapter 6 in *An Introduction to Commutative Algebra* by Atiyah and McDonald. I have known that it is closed since $\operatorname{Supp}M=V(\operatorname{Ann}M)$. But why it is Noetherian?

Comment: One should note that in general $\operatorname{Supp}M$ is not closed for an arbitrary module $M$. A sufficient condition for $\operatorname{Supp}M$ to be closed is that $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(m_i)_{1\le i\le n}$ is a set of generators of the noetherian module $M$, and $\mathfrak a_i=\operatorname{Ann}_{R}m_i$. Then
$$\operatorname{Supp}M=\bigcup_{1\le i\le n}V(\mathfrak a_i)$$
so  it  is enough to prove the assertion for a *cyclic* noetherian module.

Now, $V(\mathfrak a_i))$ is homeomorphic to $\;\operatorname{Spec}(R/\mathfrak a_i)$, and $\;R/\mathfrak a_i\simeq Rm_i\;$  is a noetherian ring, so its spectrum is a noetherian space.